# Entity Framework - Entity Find throwing no parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have the "Find" method throwing this exception when executed:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The class 'NWatch.Entities.NWatchConvertMethod' has no parameterless constructor.

Adding the ConvertMethod to the dbContext and saving changes has no problems.

Code:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Delete()
        {
            // Add the entry
            var convertMethod = RenderConvertMethod();
            dbContext.ConvertMethods.Add(convertMethod);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            int id = convertMethod.ConvertMethodId;

            // Remove entry
            dbContext.ConvertMethods.Remove(convertMethod);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Ensure the entry no longer exists in the DB
            // BELOW LINES THROWS THE EXCEPTION
            var convertMethodFromDb = dbContext.ConvertMethods.Find(id);
            Assert.IsNull(convertMethodFromDb);
        }

        private NWatchConvertMethod RenderConvertMethod()
        {
            var convertMethod = new NWatchConvertMethod("TestConvertMethod")
            {
                ConvertMethodDesc = "my description"
            };

            return convertMethod;
        }
```

Comment: well, makes sense, right?  You're asking EF to give you an object based on just an ID.  If that object requires construction parameters, then EF will have no idea how to build it.  Give the class a parameterless constructor.

Comment: So in order for EF to be able to use find an entity based on it's PK, it has to have a parameterless constructor?  I took out that constructor so from the NWatchConvertMethod entity because "Name" is something that is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All entities must have a parameterless constructor. It can be private if you want:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3820.entity-framework-faq-entity-classes.aspx#Does_the_Entity_Framework_require_objects_with_public_empty_constructors

You must add a parameterless constructor to NWatchConvertMethod.